# Aws loadbalancer configuration for websocket server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

How can I maintain websocket connection with loadbalancer.
Actually loadbalancer is rejecting wss request or https upgrade request for websocket server.

I have tried long time group level stickness also but loadblancer itself is rejecting request it is not reaching to instance